# RMI at local-network with NotBoundException-Exception after calling "lookup"

Tags: java, rmi

I got a problem on RMI:

My RMI-Client trys to get the registry of 192.168.1.37

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.1.37",1099);
String[] s = registry.list();
    for( String obj : s ) {
        System.out.println("  " + obj);
    }
IMaster master = (IMaster) registry.lookup ("rmi://192.168.1.37:1099/Master");
```

My RMI-Server looks like this:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
IMaster m = new Master(3, 3);
registry.rebind ("Master", m);
System.out.println ("Master Server is ready.");
```

The registry-List [String[] s = registry.list();] knows the "Master"-binding. That means: There is no problem on the network and the registry exists. Also the object is already exported. (I use a eclipse-plugin for RMI).

But at the lookup-line of the client i got a exception:

```
java.rmi.NotBoundException: rmi://192.168.1.37:1099/Master
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:136)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at philosoper.client.ClientServer.main(ClientServer.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at net.genady.rmi.logger.Runner.main(Runner.java:137)
```

Does any one knows how to fix this? :)
Thx

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
IMaster master = (IMaster) registry.lookup ("rmi://192.168.1.37:1099/Master");
```

to

```
IMaster master = (IMaster) registry.lookup ("Master");
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer: i replaced: "rmi://192.168.1.37:1099/Master" to "Master". Now i got a other exception: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: ..

Comment: could tell me what nested exception are you getting?

Comment: oh i am sorry looking for a proper way to post that exception(s): java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
 at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)

Comment: btw: i am using that security-polivy: grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

Comment: Are you sure you started the registry, RMI server and then starting the client.
Also make sure your port 1099 is free

Comment: using "netstat -antp" -> the ports 1099 are free and listen. After stopping the registry "netstat" says "time_wait" for 1099. I restarted the registry now again and tried again but the same nested exception as before. Nex step will be "init 0" and retry :)

Answer (score 0):

The Server didn't know his own IP. So you have to start it by telling him the ip of your server.

I use the Eclipse-Plugin: genady

So on the server in eclipse: Click on "Run Configurations..." -> "RMI VM Properties" and add that IP to "java.rmi.server.hostname"

And:

```
IMaster master = (IMaster) registry.lookup ("Master");
```

Thats all.
Thx for your help :)

Comment: Correction. *Your* server is misconfigured so that it doesn't by default *use* its *public* IP address when building RMI stubs.